# Limit the selection on UITableView to 2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I do to limit the selection of row in tableview to 2.

I mean I have a tableview with items but the user can select unlimited rows. I want to set to 2 selected row maximum.

I just made a listeSiropsSelected and put items on it, and if this list .count >= 2, display an alert. But the 3rd row is selected even if alert is show.

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("Tableview setup \(listeSirops.count) items")
        return listeSirops.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "siropCell", for: indexPath) as? ChoisirSiropTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue tabacCell")
        }
        let tabac = listeSirops[indexPath.row]
        
        
        
        cell.labelNom.text = tabac.nom
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let sirops = listeSirops[indexPath.row]
        if(listeSiropsSelected.count >= 2) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Erreur", message: "Vous ne pouvez choisir que 2 sirops.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            listeSiropsSelected.append(sirops.nom)
            print(listeSiropsSelected)
        }
        

        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let sirops = listeSirops[indexPath.row]
        let objectToRemove = sirops.nom
        
        listeSiropsSelected.remove(object: objectToRemove)
        
        print(listeSiropsSelected)
    }
```

3 rows selected, message appear but how can remove the 3rd row ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Implement `willSelectRowAt`, it prevents the selection of a cell if `nil` is returned

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    return listeSiropsSelected.count < 3 ? indexPath : nil
}
```

Delete the alert, it's not needed, the user experience is that the user is not able to select more than 2 cells.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line under `self.present`:

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //here
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, selectedRows.count > 2, let oldestIndexPath = selectedRows.first {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: oldestIndexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    let sirops = listeSirops[indexPath.row]
    let objectToRemove = sirops.nom
    
    listeSiropsSelected.remove(object: objectToRemove)
    
    print(listeSiropsSelected)
}
```